# In relation to fitness, is there a difference between the words plan, program, routine or are they interchangeable?

Tags: word-choice

In terms of fitness, what would the proper term for something that describes a set of exercises to perform?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Plan* and *routine* mean slightly different things and are together different from *program*.

- A ***plan*** is an overarching idea with certain expected events that
  will happen chronologically that help you meet a goal. "I plan to go
  to the meeting." Plans can be changed; i.e. "I originally planned to
  go, but ended up not going." *Plans* are **long term**.
- A ***routine*** is a set of chronological events that happen almost
  exactly the same each time it is performed. "I run, swim, and hike
  all in that order everyday." Routines can be interrupted but are not
  often changed, otherwise they wouldn't really be routines (unless
  something changing is routine). Routines generally do not help
  you achieve a goal; routines are more of an outcome. *Routines* are
  **short term**.
- A ***program*** is a planned series of plans (events) and that you join
  into. You either take part of a program or you don't. It is sometimes
  a club. See below. A *program* is a **set** of *plans*.

In a sentence: "I just joined a weight-training program. The plan they gave me will help improve my health. It is now a part of my morning routine."

Sometimes *program* is used interchangeably with *club*. "I joined an after school program and it helps me with my homework." The club for all intents and purposes usually has an intent and has plans set in place to complete.

*Plan* in marketing is usually used similarly to "What is your current health care plan?" In this context it usually does not involve any actual plans to do something, and is instead a way to describe your membership to some program.

Sometimes if you join a program with the intent of gaining something they will have various plans to help you on that goal as a central part of your membership. One fitness plan that a program offers may involve you running, swimming, and hiking for 30 minutes a day, and then slowly upping the duration or introducing more intense workouts later on. Another plan it may offer may include intense workouts right away.

When such participation starts happening at a fixed rate (say daily) it becomes routine. Your routine will largely stay the same (running, swimming, and hiking for 30 min each daily for 3 months, afterwards upping to 1 hr each daily for another 3 months).